# RESTful URLs for multiple resource in the same miccroservice

Tags: rest, microservices, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

We are developing a serverless application (AWS API Gateway, Lambda, and Dynamo) keeping users and groups in the same microservice as they are being stored in the same DynamoDB table. REST endpoints for the users look like this:

```
/user/invites
/user/:userId/save
/user/:userId/activate
```

Is the a good idea to have endpoints for groups look like:

```
/groups/
/groups/add/
groups/:groupId/remove
/group/:groupId/addUser/:userId
```

Is it okay to have endpoints with different "base" in the same microservice?

Answer (score 0):

Like all good answers in software, it depends!

My theory for routing is to ask about requirements: Can you look up a user without a group ID? Can you look up a group without a user ID?

If the answer to either is "yes", then that resource deserves its own route.

Compare that with something like a multi-tenant system, where an Organization has many Widgets. A widget wholly belongs to an organization, so you'd never directly query that widget.

Given this, we have:

```
/orgs/:orgId - get/put/post org info
/orgs/:orgId/widgets/:widgetID - get/put/post widget info
```

In your example, given that Groups have many users, and Users have many groups (many to many relationship), I think your provided routing scheme is correct.